# How to fill html fields with last made API call?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about rest APIs and async/await, so I'm just doing a tiny project with pokeapi.

I got an event listener on "input" that calls the API and then fills in the html fields.

The problem is, when an id is inserted e.g. "123" this will make three requests, fetchPokemon("1"), fetchPokemon("12") and fetchPokemon("123"),
for now that is not a problem. But what it sometimes does is that the second request "12" finishes
after the third request "123" so the final filled in html field is with the data from "12" request.

Is there an easy way around this to make it fill in always the last made request?

```
const pokemonId = document.getElementById("pokemon-id");
const pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon-name");
const pokemonType = document.getElementById("pokemon-type");
const pokemonHeight = document.getElementById("height");
const pokemonWeight = document.getElementById("weight");
const pokemonSearch = document.getElementById("pokemon-search");

async function fetchPokemon(idOrName) {
    const endpoint = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
    const response = await fetch(endpoint + idOrName);

    if (!response.ok) return null;

    return response.json();
}

function fillPokemonFields(pokemon) {
    if(!pokemon) return;

    pokemonId.textContent = pokemon.id;
    pokemonName.textContent = pokemon.name;
    pokemonType.textContent = pokemon.type;
    pokemonHeight.textContent = pokemon.height;
    pokemonWeight.textContent = pokemon.weight;
}

pokemonSearch.addEventListener("input", async function () {
    let input = this.value;
    let pokemon;

    // TODO validation

    pokemon = await fetchPokemon(input);
    fillPokemonFields(pokemon);
});
```

html

```
<main>
   <input type="text" id="pokemon-search">
 
   <div id="pokemon-id"></div>
   <div id="pokemon-name"></div>
   <div id="pokemon-type"></div>
   <div id="pokemon-height"></div>
   <div id="pokemon-weight"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: add Markup also to understand correctly.

Comment: It's doing "1" then "12" then "123" because it's reacting to every keystroke (every change in value) — the usual way to deal with that is to wait for a pause in typing, and/or "debounce" (google "debounce") -- otherwise you'd have to track request numbers (some sort of ID) and only call fillPokemonFields when the _most recent_ request completes.

Comment: What you’re looking for is called debouncing. Debounce the callback triggered by oninput.

Comment: Yes, for every keystroke I wanted It to do a request, so that's all as expected.

Comment: debouncing did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### The problem lies in the `.addEventListener` part.

The `input` event is almost identical to the `change` event, which means everytime a user enters a key, it gets updated. This is why it **makes 3 calls** with **1, 12 and 123**

### Solution

Instead of `input` use `submit` on the form

```
yourFormElement.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  // this is needed to avoid default functionality of the onsubmit method
  e.preventDefault();

  // do stuff here...
});
```

Comment: On-submit eliminates the ability to find-as-you-type

Comment: The whole point was that for any change on the input element it would do something, so yes it makes 3 calls, that's why I chose "input". That's no problem, the problem is sometimes it fills the html with the second request or even the first because it took longer to load.